# Method cannot be found but clojure.reflector shows otherwise

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop, dstu2-fhir

I am trying to create a dstu2 client from clojure using hapi fhir. As a template i use https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/example/GenericClientExample.java

But I am not able to execute

```
ctx.setPerformanceOptions(PerformanceOptionsEnum.DEFERRED_MODEL_SCANNING);
in clojure
```

What i do is the following:

```
(def fhir-context (. FhirContext forDstu2))
=> #'emrspp.fhir-resources/fhir-context 
(def opts PerformanceOptionsEnum/DEFERRED_MODEL_SCANNING)
=>  #'emrspp.fhir-resources/opts
```

But then the followint fails:

```
(.setPerformanceOptions fhir-context opts)
=>
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: setPerformanceOptions for class ca.uhn.fhir.context.FhirContext
```

clojure reflection gives the following :

```
(pprint (filter #(= "setPerformanceOptions" (str (:name %))) (:members  (r/reflect fhir-context))))

=> 
~
({:name setPerformanceOptions,
  :return-type void,
  :declaring-class ca.uhn.fhir.context.FhirContext,
  :parameter-types [ca.uhn.fhir.context.PerformanceOptionsEnum<>],
  :exception-types [],
  :flags #{:varargs :public}}
 {:name setPerformanceOptions,
  :return-type void,
  :declaring-class ca.uhn.fhir.context.FhirContext,
  :parameter-types [java.util.Collection],
  :exception-types [],
  :flags #{:public}})
nil
```

The imports section is:

```
 (:import [org.hl7.fhir.instance.model.api IBaseOperationOutcome IBaseResource ]
  7            [ca.uhn.fhir.context FhirContext PerformanceOptionsEnum]
  8            [ca.uhn.fhir.model.base.resource BaseOperationOutcome ]
  9            [ca.uhn.fhir.model.dstu2.resource Bundle
 10                                              Conformance Observation
 11                                              OperationOutcome
 12                                              Organization Parameters
 13                                              Patient Provenance]
 14            [ca.uhn.fhir.model.dstu2.valueset AdministrativeGenderEnum IssueSeverityEnum]
 15             [ca.uhn.fhir.model.primitive DateDt IdDt  InstantDt]
 16            [ca.uhn.fhir.rest.api  MethodOutcome SummaryEnum ]
 17            [ca.uhn.fhir.rest.client IGenericClient ServerValidationModeEnum interceptor.LoggingInterceptor ]
 18            [ca.uhn.fhir.rest.method.SearchStyleEnum ]
 19            [ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.DateRangeParam ]
 20            [ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.exceptions.PreconditionFailedException ]
 21            )
```

with no :requires except pprint and reflection

Any hits of what happens regarding the method setPerformanceOptions that appears to be there but  be executed ????

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out after hours. I closer look at the namespace : http://hapifhir.io/apidocs/ca/uhn/fhir/context/FhirContext.html
reveals that the passing argument needs to be a java collection and thus

```
(.setPerformanceOptions fhir-context opts)
```

must be changed to

```
(.setPerformanceOptions fhir-context (java.util.ArrayList. [opts]))
```

or simplier

```
(.setPerformanceOptions fhir-context [opts] )
```